# error: too few arguments to function `printDay' (C language)

Tags: c, compiler-errors

#### Question

I'm fairly new to C and I've got this error when I try to compile it (GCC):

> *error: too few arguments to function `printDay'*

My questions are:

1. What does it mean?
2. How do I fix this?

P.S this is not my full code, it's just this error I'm faced with.
Thanks in advance.

#### Code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_DAYS 31
#define MIN_DAYS 1
#define MAX_MONTHS 12
#define MIN_MONTHS 1

enum monthsOfYear
{
    jan = 1,
    feb,
    mar,
    apr,
    may,
    jun,
    jul,
    aug,
    sep,
    oct,
    nov,
    dec
};

enum daysOfWeek
{
    sun = 1,
    mon,
    tue,
    wed,
    thu,
    fri,
    sat
};

int input();
void check(int month, int day);
void printDay(int month, int day, int firstDay);

int main()
{
    printf("Hello! Welcome to the day calculator!\n");
    printDay(input());
    return (0);
} 

/*this function takes the input from the user
input: none
output: the first day
*/ 
int input()
{
    enum daysOfWeek day = 0;
    enum monthsOfYear month = 0;
    
    int firstDay = 0;
    
    printf("Enter month to check: (1-jan, 2-feb, etc) ");
    scanf("%d", &month);
    printf("Enter day to check: ");
    scanf("%d", &day);
    check(month,day);
    printf("Enter the weekday of the 1st of the month: (1-Sunday, 2-Monday, etc) ");
    scanf("%d", &firstDay);
    
    return firstDay;
}

/*
this function checks the validity of the input
input: day, month
output: none
*/
void check(int month, int day)
{
    if(month > MAX_MONTHS || month < MIN_MONTHS && day > MAX_DAYS || day < MIN_DAYS)
    {
        printf("Invalid input, try again\n");
        input();
    }
    if (month == feb && day > 28)
    {
        printf("Invalid input, try again\n");
        input();
    }
    if (month == jan && day > 31)
    {
        printf("Invalid input, try again\n");
        input();
    }
}

void printDay(int month, int day, int firstDay)
{
    int date = 0;
    date = day - firstDay;
    switch(day)
    {
        case sun:
        printf("%d.%d will be a Sunday", day, month);
        break;
        
        default: 
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What does it mean?

"*error: too few arguments to function 'printDay'*" means you're passing the wrong number of argument to `printDay` when you call it here:

```
printDay(input());
```

You're passing one argument but your declaration of `printDay` shows that it takes 3 arguments:

```
void printDay(int month, int day, int firstDay);
```

> 2. How do I fix this?

You can fix it by passing the correct number of arguments, e.g:

```
int month = ...;
int day = ...;
int firstDay = ...;
printDay(month, day, firstDay);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that I've found the source of the error:

On line 45, you have *`printDay(input());`*
It makes me think that this is the error because the message is, "*error: too few arguments to function `printDay'*", and you are only passing **one parameter**!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can't explain better than @tuple_cat!

Answer (score 1):

You declared (and defined) the function `printDay` with `3` parameters:

```
void printDay(int month, int day, int firstDay);
```

but you called it only with `1` parameter

```
printDay(input());
```

(as the function `input()` returns - as all functions in C - only `1` value, in your case of type `int`).

Answer (score 0):

1. What does it mean?

error: too few arguments to function(.......) means you are passing fewer arguments than the parameters. You should pass an equal parameter as your function hold. If your function holds three parameters then you must input three parameters for calling the function.

2. How to fix it?

Just input equal variables as the function parameters.